# Aurelia set element on ViewModel

Tags: aurelia

How would you add a component to a View from the ViewModel. For example, I have the following:

I have a service injected into a component. Then from the component I fetch data and when I get the response I set the `data` property to the fetched data. After this I would like to mount the component to the View with the fetched data as a bindable.

```
this.service.get()
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data =>{ 
    this.data = data.results
    //Mount element to View here: <component data.bind="data"></component>
})
```

Im asking this question because if I set the value when fetched and on the View to this:

```
<component data.bind="data"></component>
```

It passes an empty object. I have tried using the service on the `canActivate` and `activate` methods.

Component:

```
export class Component{
   @bindable data
   bind(){
      console.log(this.data)
   }
}
```

Comment: What does `component` look like?

Comment: I updated my question. If I log data it is an empty array.

Comment: As far as I can see, that shouldn't be an issue. Perhaps there is something breaking your code. Show the full code of your web component and service

Comment: This the whole project: https://github.com/DiegoGallegos4/aurelia-test. You can check the empleado folder: service, view and viewmodel are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code in to a gist and ran it on gist.run here: https://gist.run/?id=04907ff8d8b6d8b4aee625669d8571a3

It runs as expected for me. I even updated it to set the data inside a promise.

Now, if you want to be notified when the `data` property changes, you'll need to implement a function called `${propertyName}Changed(newValue, oldValue)` so in this case, `dataChanged(newValue, oldValue)`. I created a separate gist to show how you might want to change your code: https://gist.run/?id=34a01ca3f600470691d5b91c9131f33b

You'll notice in my code I didn't use the `newValue` and `oldValue` parameters. I did this on purpose to let you know that Aurelia still sets the property value. The callback is just there to let your code do stuff when the property value changes.

Comment: Great it works! What solved the problem is that I return my promise as you did on activate. What is the difference on returning a promise and not? In what conditions should I attach a component to the DOM from the ViewModel?

Comment: When you return a promise from `activate`, Aurelia will wait for it to resolve before continuing with the component lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

The "data" field being bound to is a field on the ViewModel using your component, not a field in your component.

Comment: Yes I know. That why on the Component it has **@bindable data**. Static data gets binded to component but whenever I do a fetch on the server it doesn't. Besides the question is about mounting a component from the view model to view. In this case <component>.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos You can use show.bind="isReadyToShow" to add and remove your component from the DOM. isReadyToShow would be a boolean property on the ViewModel not the component.